# Unable to set value of leading in TextInput

Tags: apache-flex

I need to set the value of leading of text layer in Photoshop. I am first retrieving the selected text layer and then gets its value in a TextItem object. Then I get the value of the leading from a combo-box and set the value of leading using the following code.

var activeTextItem:TextItem = curLayer.textItem;
activeTextItem.leading = ComboBox.text.toString();

This code works fine when using on Windows. But when I try to execute the above code on Mac it always shows the leading as null object.
Can someone please guide me why I am not able to set the value of leading in Mac?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think this will solve your issue, but you're using the toString method on a String. It's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. 
The leading has a value called Auto which by default has value a null. Therefore when I use the above code I am not able to set the value as leading parameter is null.

To overcome this I put a check that if leading is null value ie Auto then set the property useAutoLeading to false and once you set the value then again set the useAutoLeading property to true.

```
if("Auto" == ComboBox.text)
{
activeTextItem.useAutoLeading = false;
activeTextItem.leading = ComboBox.text.valueOf();
activeTextItem.useAutoLeading = true;
}
```

Thanks.